# FindClass crashes in Android NDK

Tags: java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have a purely native Android app, where the entry point is:

```
 void android_main(struct android_app* state) 
 {
 }
```

I need to access device information such as, android.os.Build.MODEL and in my android_main, have the following:

```
JNIEnv *env = state->activity->env;
    jclass build_class = env->FindClass("android/os/Build");
    jfieldID brand_id = env->GetStaticFieldID(build_class, "MODEL", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring brand_obj = (jstring)env->GetStaticObjectField(build_class, brand_id);
const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(brand_obj, 0);
```

Unfortunately it crashes at the second line - "FindClass". I know that `env` is not null because I checked for this, but otherwise I am unable to debug this and find out why it is crashing :(

Comment: Where did you get the env from? Is it cached ? The only way FindClass will crash is if something is wrong with env

Comment: I am using the android_native_app_glue.h file. This defines the`android_app` struct, the parameter to my `android_main`. This contains a `ANativeActivity` pointer, which is what contains the `JNIEnv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had to:

```
 state->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
```

instead of

```
 JNIEnv *env = state->activity->env;
```

This post was helpful:
http://blog.tewdew.com/post/6852907694/using-jni-from-a-native-activity

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively , you can do this in native code :-

```
#include <sys/system_properties.h>
#define ANDROID_OS_BUILD_MODEL               "ro.product.model"       

char model_id[PROP_VALUE_MAX]; // PROP_VALUE_MAX from <sys/system_properties.h>.
int len;
len = __system_property_get(ANDROID_OS_BUILD_MODEL, model_id);
```

// On return, len will equal (int)strlen(model_id).

model_id will contain the req info

Refer [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Build.java) for all constants